# Heroku Cedar assets:precompile has beef with attr_protected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

Here's an odd issue:

- One of my ActiveRecord models uses `attr_protected`
- `attr_protected` must connect to the database (surprise! gotcha!)
- [On Heroku Cedar, the database is not available during slug compilation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting).

Workaround:

- Use `attr_accessible` instead
- [Other people have used this workaround](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/pull/98)

Is there a better solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need access to your application models when precompiling? If not then

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

Is supposed to do the trick

Comment: Also see http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/labs-user-env-compile to make your env variables available at slug compile time.

Comment: @JohnBeynon Thanks, that was just the thing I was looking for